# Copy and Base Constructor don't initialize C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

When calling the constructor with a default constructor argument no object gets constructed.

```
    class cl{
private:
public:
    cl(){cout << "Default used" << endl;};
    cl(const cl & cl_object) {cout << "Copy used" << endl;};
    cl & operator=(const cl & cl_object){cout << "Assignment used" << endl; return *this;};
};
```

When I write:

```
cl(cl());
```

no message gets displayed.

Questions:
1) Why no object is constructed ?
2) Why the copy constructor is not used ?

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you explain how this is a duplicate ?

Comment: Like the answer says, `cl(cl());` declares a function.  Since it is a function and not a variable you're not going to see any constructor calls since you don't construct anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver So if I am understanding it correctly using cl(); only constructs an object but using cl(cl()); declares a function. But if it declares a function shouldn't the compiler output an error since I didn't specify the return type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most vexing parse

```
cl(cl());
```

is parsed as function declaration.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler output an error since I didn't specify the return type ?

Comment: My understanding is that it is a function called cl with argument of type class cl. But it still has no return type. In my compiler if I don't specify the return type it returns an error. So what happens here ?

Comment: Is is parsed as `c1 c1()` so function `c1` (which hides class `c1`) with return type `c1` (the class).

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for the clarification. If possible could you add that to your answer for other people with the same question ?

Comment: There is a duplicate. So I expected the redirection of flow.